# Random variables and characteristic function, a small doubt here.

Tags: random-variables, characteristic-functions

I'm first approaching random variables and right after definition I have this: Let $\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3, \dots \}$ be a sample space. Then the image of the random variable is a set like this:

$\mathcal{Im}(X) = \{t_1, t_2, t_3, \dots \}$ with at most countably many $t_j$, which are real numbers.

Of course, then , $X^{-1}(t_j) = E_j$ is an event.

It follows that $X(\omega) = \{t_j \quad \text{if}\;\; \omega \in E_j \} = \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty t_j\mathcal{X}_{E_j}(\omega)$

where $\mathcal{X}_{E_j}(\omega)$ is the indicator function of $E_j$.

What should be $\omega$ in this case? It's confusing to me that we use some index for $\omega$ when defining the sample set, and we don't use any when talking about the random variable.

Comment: $\omega\in\Omega$, so $\omega=\omega_i$ for some $i$